# In Selenium, after matching certain condition, click on the first delete button

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, find, element

I am trying to test adding and deleting blog post using selenium. We already have a few blog entries in our system which I do NOT want to delete, only the one which I created. So in the example below, you'll see "My blog"  followed by name="ctl00$ctl00$OuterTaskRegion$TaskRegion$TaskRegion$PostList1$theposts$ctl02$DeleteButton" value="Delete" 
and then another blog item followed by delete. I want to click the delete button after "My Blog"

```
   <tr>
            <td class="CommonListCellLeftMost">
                <span><a href/2015/05/15/my-blog.aspx">
                    My blog </a></span>
                <div style="font-size:.8em; color:#959595">
                Drafted by
               QATest1
                on
                May 15, 2015
                at
                2:32 PM
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="CommonListCell PostViewsCell">
                    <a href="/cs/controlpanel/blogs/views.aspx? WeblogID=103&WeblogPostID=131221">
                    0</a>
            </td>
            <td class="CommonListCell PostCommentsCell">
                <a href="/cs/controlpanel/blogs/comments.aspx?WeblogID=103&WeblogPostID=131221">
                    0</a>
            </td>
            <td class="CommonListCell PostImageStatusCell">
                <img src="/cs/unpublished.gif"
                    title="Unpublished"/>
            </td>
            <td  class="CommonListCell" nowrap="nowrap">
                <input type="button"      onclick="window.location='/posteditor.aspx"value="Edit" />
                <input type="submit"     name="ctl00$ctl00$OuterTaskRegion$TaskRegion$TaskRegion$PostList1$theposts$ctl02     $DeleteButton" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm(&#39;Delete? \n(this     action cannot be undone)&#39;);"       id="ctl00_ctl00_OuterTaskRegion_TaskRegion_TaskRegion_PostList1_theposts_ctl02_D        eleteButton" />
            </td>
          </tr>

        <tr class="AltListRow">
            <td class="CommonListCellLeftMost">
                <span><a href="/cs/community/b/blog/archive/2015/05/12/not-           mine.aspx">
                   not mine</a></span>
                <div style="font-size:.8em; color:#959595">
                Published by
                QAguestB
                on
                May 12, 2015
                at
                4:05 PM
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="CommonListCell PostViewsCell">
                <a href="/cs/controlpanel/blogs/views.aspx?   WeblogID=103&WeblogPostID=131216">
                    8</a>
            </td>
            <td class="CommonListCell PostCommentsCell">
                <a href="/cs/controlpanel/blogs/comments.aspx?   WeblogID=103&WeblogPostID=131216">
                    0</a>
            </td>
            <td class="CommonListCell PostImageStatusCell">
                <img src="/cs/controlpanel/images/comment/published.gif"
                    title="Published"/>
            </td>
            <td  class="CommonListCell">
                <input type="button"    onclick="window.location='/cs/controlpanel/blogs/posteditor.aspx?    SelectedNavItem=Posts&WeblogID=103&WeblogPostID=131216';" value="Edit" />
                <input type="submit"     name="ctl00$ctl00$OuterTaskRegion$TaskRegion$TaskRegion$PostList1$theposts$ctl03         $DeleteButton" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure    you want to delete this post? \n(this action cannot be undone)&#39;);"    id="ctl00_ctl00_OuterTaskRegion_TaskRegion_TaskRegion_PostList1_theposts_ctl03_D       eleteButton" />
            </td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: This question is extremely vague. You don't even indicate what you think the problem might be or what you've done to try and solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an XPath expression checking the `My Blog` text and locating the delete button:

```
//tr[contains(td/span/a, "My blog")]/td/input[@value = "Delete"]
```